# Can a person taking their undergraduate degree in humanities, apply for a masters in scientific fields?

Tags: graduate-admissions

can humanities students apply for masters in the sciences or must they take a second undergraduate degree in the sciences if they choose to study in a different field?

Comment: Are you still in your bachelor's? What country?

Comment: @Azor Ahai Yes, In the US

Comment: You can apply to any course you wish. Getting accepted is a different question.

Comment: This is quite possible in the US, but less so elsewhere, as the undergraduate program is quite different here than in, say, UK or Germany.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the stated requirements of the program you're interested in. There's no easy answer.

Example: if you're interested in a Masters in Biology @ Harvard Extension School, then you're in luck because [their website](https://www.extension.harvard.edu/academics/graduate-degrees/biology-degree/degree-requirements) says:

> Eligibility: Before enrolling in any degree-applicable courses, you need to possess a four-year, US regionally accredited bachelor's degree or its foreign equivalent. You cannot already have or be in the process of earning a master's degree in biology or related field.

So you should be in the clear. However if you want to do Aeronautics and Astronautics @ MIT, [then](https://aeroastro.mit.edu/graduate-program/admission/admission-criteria):

> You must have a strong background in mathematics and physics, and, with rare exception, familiarity with an engineering discipline. In some cases, unfulfilled entrance requirements may be satisfied during your first year of graduate study. If you're radically changing fields, advanced study before applying is recommended. You should also address your reasons for changing you field when you are writing your Statement of Objectives, a very important part of our graduate application.

It's up to you to assess if you have a strong background in mathematics & physics from your humanities degree, and if so, to convince the admissions people.

Comment: Since the OP is currently in their bachelor's, I would recommend - if they don't want to change majors entirely - to squeeze in as many relevant science courses as they can. No master's will take anyone who took 0 relevant calsses.